# Is there a way to retrieve data from an entrybox in a specific frame in Python Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, get, frame

I'm making a python Tkinter GUI.

I'm trying to make a way to create unlimited 'task tabs'. This means unlimited frames. Each 'tab' (frame) has the same entry box in it.

Is there a way to retrieve data from a specific frame? I understand using .get() works, but how can I .get() from a specific frame?

For example, if:

taskTab1 Entry box contains "hello"

and

taskTab2 Entry box contains "goodbye"

how can I retrieve the info from taskTab1. If I used .get() I'd be grabbing the entry from taskTab2.

Thanks

Comment: It is better to keep a reference of the entries in a list but you can also use: `<tk.Frame>.winfo_children()`. That will return a list of all of the frame's children

Comment: There's nothing special you need to do. In python -- not just tkinter -- to call a method on an object you simply need a reference to that object. Your description of the problem is very unclear. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: btw if You have single entry boxes then there is no need to create a frame for each of those

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of doing something like this I can think of is this:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Entry, Button


root = Tk()

for i in range(10):
    frame = Frame(root)
    frame.pack()

    entry = Entry(frame)
    entry.pack(side='left')

    Button(frame, text='Get Text', command=lambda e=entry: print(e.get())).pack(side='right')

root.mainloop()
```

(Could also use `partial` function from `functools` but this seems to be simpler) Basically the button gets assigned a function that will always execute with the specific Entry widget given to it, so the one that is next to it in this case.